# Failed to Notarize (Code sign) Electron Node.js app on MacOs

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I tried to notarize (Code sign) Electron Node.js app using **Electron forge** to submit it to Mac App Store (MAS) by following the option **Using an app-specific password** mentioned in [Electron forge official guide](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/code-signing/code-signing-macos#option-1-using-an-app-specific-password), but encountering error - **"Failed to staple your application with code: 66. Cannot download ticket. CDHash must be set."**

**My app's forge.config.js file is as follows (ensured that appleId, appleIdPassword, teamId are accuarte):**

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    osxSign: {},
    osxNotarize: {
      tool: 'notarytool',
      appleId: '******',
      appleIdPassword: '******',
      teamId: '******',
    }
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

**My Node.js application's package.json has the scripts as follows:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
```

But on executing npm run make to do code signing and generate the app, encountering the following error repeatedly on multiple retries:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Failed to staple your application with code: 66

Processing: /private/var/folders/h3/vkfpv17950z45hg1z5tjfq000000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/myapp-darwin-x64-wgLqgW/myapp.app
Properties are {
    NSURLIsDirectoryKey = 1;
    NSURLIsPackageKey = 1;
    NSURLIsSymbolicLinkKey = 0;
    NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey = Application;
    NSURLTypeIdentifierKey = "com.apple.application-bundle";
    "_NSURLIsApplicationKey" = 1;
}
Props are {
}
Cannot download ticket. CDHash must be set.
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/myapp/node_modules/@electron/notarize/lib/staple.js:22:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/path/myapp/node_modules/@electron/notarize/lib/staple.js:4:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Can you please help debug the reason for the failure?

Comment: Hello, I faced same issue have you get any solutions for that?

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well. Any update on this?